# C++ - Does anyone have any tricks for analyzing pointer to pointer problems?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I've been given a set of different Pointer to Pointer exercises. Each dereferencing an array of pointers. It's definitely challenging and confusing when analyzing them without a compiler. Does anyone have any systematic tricks to solve them?

```
int main(void)
{
    const char* s[] = { "AB", "XY", "EZ"};
    const char** z = s;
    z += 1;


    cout << "The value of **z is: " << **z << endl;
    cout << "The value of *z is: " << *z << endl;
    cout << "The value of **(z-1) is: " << **(z-1)<< endl;
    cout << "The value of *(z-1) is: " << *(z-1)<< endl;
    cout << "The value of z[1][1] is: " << z[1][1]<< endl;
    cout << "The value of *(*(z+1)+1) is: " << *(*(z+1)+1)<< endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I have another puzzle here, which is definitely a little bit shorter.

```
int foo[] = {1, 4, 9};
int bar[] = {16, 26, 36, 49};

int main(void){
    int *x[2];
    x[0] = bar;
    x[1] = foo;
    *x[1] = (*x)[1];
    //What changes?
}
```

I was able to get the correct results after a while, but I cannot consistently get the correct answers.

I'm looking for a trick similar to reading a function containing "const" right to left. I.e.

```
const char **x;
```

"x is a pointer to a char pointer that is constant."

### ANSWERS BELOW:

### -

### -

### -

The answers are:
**z is X, *z is XY, **(z-1) is A, *(z-1) is AB, z[1][1] is Z, * ( *(z+1)+1) is Z.

Comment: I think the answer to the last question is that `1` in `foo` changes to `26`. I think it is pretty straightforward manual calculation. It is highly error prone but I don't think there are *tricks* to solve these kind of questions. You shouldn't actually even end up in these situations in C++. There's pretty much everything in the standard library to do it more nicely.

Comment: Thank you. Forgot to include that in the solutions.

Comment: Pointers to pointers are a bad practice. It is ambiguous if they represent Arrays or Single values.

Comment: It's definitely ambiguous and annoying. However, this is for a Software Engineering course, and content like this is being tested.

Comment: @NateM I figured as much. Some teachers think that C++ is C. Some never tell you later that it isn't, that there are better options. Well, even C has better options...

Comment: In the first exercise, the most important thing to notice is that `cout` has different overloads for `char` and `char*`. When you `cout` a `char`, it prints the character; when you `cout` a `char*`, it prints the C-string.

Comment: Something of interest might be the [Spiral Rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) but it is remotely related to the question but does help when you have complicated data types (especially when you are dealing with pointers to functions).

Comment: Learn that `*(X+Y)` means `X[Y]`, make sure you understand the operator precedence in `*x[1]`. You can also draw memory diagrams

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no tricks, it's just a matter of understanding the mechanics of each piece of the puzzle. Let's break it down.

```
z += 1;
```

`z` starts at `s[0]`, so now it's `s[1]`.

```
cout << "The value of **z is: " << **z << endl;
```

`**z` is the same as `*s[1]`, which is the same as `s[1][0]`. Which is `'X'`.

```
cout << "The value of *z is: " << *z << endl;
```

`*z` is the same as `s[1]`, which is a `char*` pointer pointing to `XY`.

```
cout << "The value of **(z-1) is: " << **(z-1)<< endl;
```

`**(z-1)` is the same as `*s[0]`. Which is `'A'`.

```
cout << "The value of *(z-1) is: " << *(z-1)<< endl;
```

By now the pattern should be obvious, this is `s[0]` which is a pointer to `"AB"`.

```
cout << "The value of z[1][1] is: " << z[1][1]<< endl;
```

`z[1]` is the same as `*(z+1)`; since `z` is already `s+1`, that means the expression is the same as `*(s+2)` or `s[2]`. Taking an additional subscript from that is indexing into the pointer at `s[2]`, so `s[2][1]` is the second character of the string or `'Z'`.

```
cout << "The value of *(*(z+1)+1) is: " << *(*(z+1)+1)<< endl;
```

Working our way from the inside parenthesis out, `*(z+1)` we've already determined is `s[2]`. Adding `1` to that pointer gets to the second character just as in the previous example, and dereferencing that pointer with `*` results in the character `'Z'`.

Comment: Thank you. That makes a lot of sense and I definitely agree with it. I like applying the `[]` to the code and getting rid of the `*`. How would one go about the final exercise containing foo and bar. Would you be willing to break that one down?

Comment: @NateM it wouldn't be sporting of me to give you the whole answer once I've shown you how to do it, would it?

Comment: Fair enough, but I managed to get it myself applying precedence to `[]` over `*` as `[]` is binary and `*` is unary.

Answer (score 0):

So I don't know if this is the most efficient way of doing it, but the way I understand it is that `[]` and `*` are almost interchangeable for pointer to pointers. It's almost like a 2D array. It's just that `[]` has a higher precedence than *.

Therefore, looking at `**z`, we can analyze it as `z[0][0]`. For a more challenging example, we can analyze `**(z-1)` as `z[-1][0]`. Finally, the most challenging, `*(*(z+1)+1)` can be analyzed as `z[+1][+1]`.